# Proof of the BOOK: Bertrand's Postulate, $\prod_{p \leq {2m+1}} p=\left(\prod_{p \leq m+1} p\right)\left(\prod_{{m+1}< p \leq 2m+1} p\right)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a question concerning Bertrand's postulate in "Proofs from the BOOK", on [page 8](http://books.google.com/books?id=CuTpgZaLahkC&pg=PA8):

$$\prod_{p \leq {2m+1}} p=\left(\prod_{p \leq m+1} p \right)\left( \prod_{{m+1} <p \leq 2m+1} p\right)$$

Why did the author split the product up in the way he did it and not in another way? Are there any reasons?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just continue reading the proof and the reason will become apparent...

Comment: Ah ok, just read it. Sorry for asking.

Comment: So the thing to do now is to post the answer you have found, and then accept it, so we can all get on with other things. It may sound like a strange idea, but it's actually the way the site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question, but I found the reason:

For the first product holds

$$\prod_{p \leq m+1} p \leq 4^m$$

and for the 2nd

$$\prod_{{m+1} <p \leq 2m+1} p \leq \binom{2m+1}{m}$$

especially $\binom{2m+1}{m}=\frac{2m+1!}{m!m+1!}$ and thus, we get for the 2nd intervall primes which divides not the denominator but the numerator.

Comment: It's possible within 23h